# ABS Theme.Sherlock.Dialog shows Dialog Title on GingerBread

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have an activity in my manifest defined as android:theme="Theme.Sherlock.Dialog".In the OnCreate function of the activity for this dialog, I have set requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); On ICS sets this works fine. I get a dialog with no header, but on GingerBread phones the header of the Dialog still appears with a Header a blue line and my content below that. Here is what I am doing

```
<activity
        android:name=".activity.PictureChooserDialog"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="Set a Picture To Upload"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeWithCorners" />


<style name="ThemeWithCorners" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/dialog_round_corners</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">false</item>
</style>


public class PictureChooserDialog extends SherlockActivity {

protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog_picture_chooser_layout);

    //The dialog content

    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelDialog))
            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    finish();

                }
            });

}

private class CustomClickListener implements ClickListener {

    public void onClick(final int index) {
        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        }

    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

read the post on https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/500. Had to change android.view.Window to com.actionbarsherlock.view.Window. The setWindowFeature then works.